# Unity OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter does not work even with Debug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title mentions, my unity project's triggers do not work. It's weird because it works for another project but it doesn't for this one project. I searched other references and it said to have one be a rigid body, have 'isTrigger' turned on, etc. I followed all of that and it still does not work. Please help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

public class MoveAgent : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Transform targetTransform;

    public override void OnEpisodeBegin(){
        transform.position = new Vector3(42.59956f, 18.9153f, 144.7489f);
    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor){
        sensor.AddObservation(transform.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(targetTransform.position);
    }

    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions){
        float moveX = actions.ContinuousActions[0];
        float moveZ = actions.ContinuousActions[1];

        float moveSpeed = 2f;

        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ) * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut){
        ActionSegment<float> continuousActions = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
        continuousActions[0] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        continuousActions[1] = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        Debug.Log("CollisionEnter");
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        Debug.Log("Trigger!");
        if (other.TryGetComponent<Goal>(out Goal goal)){
            SetReward(+1f);
            EndEpisode();
        }

        if (other.TryGetComponent<Wall>(out Wall wall)){
            SetReward(-1f);
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im sure you are aware of the collision matrix.  Firstly you are moving the position by teleporting not by physics which doesnt help. Second. Of you dont meet the criteria  of the collision matrix it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I find the way to fix this issue form
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411980/14541130)
and [collider](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/09/04/unity-collider-explained/)

You can fix by adding **Rigidbody** to an agent or some object.

For detail.

1. Select Agent object.
2. On the inspector window click `Add Component`.
3. Select `Physics` -> `Rigidbosy`
4. Uncheck `Use Gravity` box.
5. Done!